# Rellenar/dar valor celda Google SpreadSheet

Tags: java, google-hoja-de-cálculo

os comento mi problema:

Estoy tratando de dar valores a las diferentes celdas de una hoja de cálculo de `Google` desde `Java`. Actualmente lo que hago es instanciar un objeto de la clase `CellEntry` al que le indico el texto y la celda concreta y luego se la inserto al `WorksheetEntry`.

Con esto ya se que introduce un valor concreto, pero se me queda corto, necesito encontrar la forma de darle un estilo a la celda, es decir, color de fondo, texto en negrita...

He encontrado que al `CellEntry` se le puede setear el contenido con un `TextConstruct`, el cual tiene un método estático para insertar código `HTML` y que he probado, pero lamentablemente me ha dado el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Field is server-generated.

El `HTML` introducido ha sido el siguiente:

```
<div><a href=\"http://whoa!\">whoa</a></div>
```

Sabéis que estoy haciendo mal?
Se os ocurre otra forma para poder hacer lo que quiero?

Y otra duda, sabéis si se pueden concatenar varias celdas y tratarlas cómo si sólo fueran una?

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Miguel. ¿Has logrado algún avance con respecto a este tema?

Comment: Que va, lo que hago ahora es cambiar a mano la celda pero no he conseguido automatizarlo. Tienes alguna posible solución?

Comment: que versión del api estás usando?

Comment: @FelipeM, me has hecho mirarlo (pues llevo todo el año sin tocarlo). Tengo la 3.0 (desconozco si hay una más nueva). Sabes cómo se podría hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de casi un año, y cuando he podido sacar tiempo para retomar el proyecto, he conseguido lograr mi objetivo con la versión 4 de la API.
Para el próximo, que sepa que aquí tiene la solución https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/formatting?hl=es-419